# Bulk Insert from sqlcmd not firing trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, bulk, sqlcmd

I'm using `sqlcmd` in a batch file to do weekly imports.

```
sqlcmd -U xxxx -P xxxx -i E:\data\importtc.sql
```

The command is executing,

```
bulk insert [xxxx].[dbo].[Stage] 
   from 'E:\Acct\timecards\timecard.txt' 
   with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n', FIRE_TRIGGERS)
go
```

From inside the SQL Server Management Studio, this works fine. However when I exec it from `SQLCMD` it won't fire the trigger that manipulates some of the data.

Anyone encountered this before? Thank you.